# Identify new records using PIG scripts

Tags: apache-pig

I need to Identify new records (Update and Insert) using pig scripts using fixed width file

Below are 2 dummy files -

## 25th DEC 2015

Name(31) address(39) contact(14) month(10) start date(16) value date(16) NOM(7) total(15)
tata consultáncy sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july 20-10-15    25-12-2015  TCS 95000
logicá sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july   20-10-15    25-12-2015  TCS 95000
quant sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july    20-10-15    25-12-2015  las 95000
Creative consulting sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july  20-10-15    25-12-2015  cs 0095000
lake dew consultancy 113 pérk street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july  20-10-15    25-12-2015  ldS 00095000

Creative sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july 20-10-15    25-12-2015  CS  95000
hindustan computer 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july    20-10-15    25-12-2015  TCS 95000

acia computer 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july 20-10-15    25-12-2015  TCS 095000

## 26th dev 2015

Name(31) address(39) contact(14) month(10) start date(16) value date(16) NOM(7) total(15)
tata consultáncy sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july 20-10-15    25-12-2015  TCS 95000
logicá sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july   20-10-15    25-12-2015  TCS 95000
quant sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july    20-10-15    25-12-2015  las 95000
Creative consulting sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july  20-10-15    25-12-2015  cs 0095000
lake dew consultancy 113 pérk street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july  20-10-15    25-12-2015  ldS 00095000

Creative sérvices 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july 20-10-15    25-12-2015  CS  95000
hindustan computer 113 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july    20-10-15    25-12-2015  TCS 95000

acia computer 103 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july 20-10-15    25-12-2015  ACS 098000
CREST computer 123 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july    20-10-15    25-12-2015  CRS 0900

## Expected output is #

acia computer 103 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july 20-10-15    25-12-2015  ACS 098000
CREST computer 123 park street globalview kolkota 16 9030303030 july    20-10-15    25-12-2015  CRS 0900

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
file1 = LOAD 'file1path' USING PigStorage() AS line:chararray;
file2 = LOAD 'file2path' USING PigStorage() AS line:chararray;

rightOuter = JOIN file1 RIGHT OUTER file2;
file2Only = FILTER rightOuter BY file1::line IS NULL;
file2Only = FOREACH file2Only GENERATE file2::line AS line;

DUMP file2Only;
```